# Can I make a X-server to read keyboard and mouse from another windows machine?

Tags: windows, linux, remote-control, external-display

I have 2 PC, one using Linux and another using Windows7. I want to use both display cards with the windows machine.

I cannot find such virtual device for windows. 
So, since it is possible to run X programs on the Linux machine using its own X-server, how can I use a remote keyboard and mouse,which is owned by the windows machine, to operate the X-server?

Of course the operation should be switchable between by some combined-keys.

(Just because I have place for 2 LCD, but no place for 2 keyboard & mouse.
I know dual-display, and I am using my laptop to connect one of the LCD.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing that comes to mind is remote access software such as [VNC](http://www.realvnc.com/). You could also set up [X forwarding](http://www.ssh.com/support/documentation/online/ssh/adminguide/32/X11_Forwarding.html) and display the apps locally.

If you are willing to use an entire display dedicated to the Linux box, [Synergy](http://synergy-foss.org/) may be for you.

> Synergy lets you easily share your mouse and keyboard between multiple
>   computers on your desk, and it's Free and Open Source. Just move your
>   mouse off the edge of one computer's screen on to another. You can
>   even share all of your clipboards. All you need is a network
>   connection. Synergy is cross-platform (works on Windows, Mac OS X and
>   Linux).

[image]

Comment: About X forwarding, I think the X-server will be operated only from where the X-server runs, NOT where the display exported from.

So it is not for my situation.

Synergy+ is what I miss. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah I was a little confused on the question, hopefully one of the solutions suits your needs :)